# Creating a statistics page with graphs in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm, chart.js

I created a dashboard of ng2 smart table for displaying health data in angular and now I have to create another page for statistics that displays data as graphs from the ng2 smart table when we select location from a  drop down menu , then a date range picker and a submit button , Could you help me with this ?

Need to display required data from the ng2 smart table that only display as per the filters (location selected from the drop down menu and date range where the patients took the test) and displaying it as bar diagram using chart.js

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.